# Can't pull all media files from heroku using git pull heroku master

Tags: django, git, heroku

So I was using Django admin page from the Heroku server to add some data that includes static pictures, and when I wanted to pull that pictures to my local project it shows the usual

```
Already up-to-date.
```

message.
I have tried cloning the project but still don't get the files that I need.
and yes the pictures are there because I can open it from the Django admin page and there is no `.gitignore` in my project.
This is my staticfile settings in settings.py
[image: staticfiles]

I know that I was supposed to work locally then push, but it was already done and I want to know is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Maybe check your `.gitignore`? You might be ignoring those?

Comment: there is no gitignore in my project

Comment: Okay edit your post with your settings about the static files.

Comment: are you talking about static files? (CSS/Images/Javascript) 
or Media-Files / user-uploaded content?

Comment: yes i am talking about media files